# How to succinctly express the phenomenon of hidden/surprise complications in regards of time estimates?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Is there an idiom/phrase for when you tell someone you'll have something done at a given time, but then more complications arise and it extends the time needed? For example, I'm working on a project and everything seems like it's done, and when I test it, something has broken, and now it'll take more time to finish.

Comment: When providing an estimate for a "job completion timescale", [*always allow for **contingencies***.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22always+allow+for+contingencies%22)

Comment: It could depend on the type of work. You encountered unforeseeable roadblocks, you discovered bugs in the system/program, you hit a snag during testing, etc.

Comment: __Risk__ should cover the bill. The answer to risk is to pad the planning with a percentage of the estimated time, a figure that had better be rooted in experience.

Comment: Look up contingencies.

Comment: Something about not counting one's chickens?

Answer (score 1):

These unforeseen problems are often called **glitches**.

> **glitch** : a small problem or fault that prevents something from being successful or working as well as it should:
>
> We'd expected a few glitches, but everything's gone remarkably smoothly.
>
> The system has been plagued with glitches ever since its launch.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/glitch)

One can express the possibility of such things arising by saying :

> Barring glitches, we'll be done in three days.

Answer (score 0):

In software development this is often called the [80/20 rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle), which is properly stated as:

> The first 80% of the functionality takes 20% of the time; the remaining 20% of the functionality takes the remaining 80% of the time.

but is arguably more accurately stated as:

> The first 80% of the functionality takes 80% of the time; the remaining 20% of the functionality takes the remaining 80% of the time.

for a total of 160%.